# C# WPF Expander with multiple functioning buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, button, expander

I've got an expander (code below), to which I've added a StackPanel and a few buttons. They all show when I test the code, however I can't figure out how to code a click event for the buttons. Any ideas on how to get this functioning?

```
<Expander x:Name="DBListing" ExpandDirection="Down" Header="DB List" Background="#FF644117" Foreground="LightGoldenrodYellow">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button x:Name="EdiBtn" Content="EDI DB" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="100" Height="30" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" Foreground="#FF644117"/>
        <Button x:Name="IssuesBtn" Content="Issues DB" Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="100" Height="30" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" Foreground="#FF644117"/>
        <Button x:Name="InterimBtn" Content="Interim DB" Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="100" Height="30" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" Foreground="#FF644117"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Expander>
```

I've tried setting up a click event for each button separately in the xaml.cs file, and I've also tried to set up a switch statement for the Expander. No luck thus far.

Comment: You need to be more specific on future on the *exact* issue. See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to the `Click` event in the Xaml by these steps.

1. In the button where you want the operation to be associated type `Click=`. Once done Visual Studio intellesense will offer a name as a popup. Click on that to accept. Notice how the attribute is now filled out like `Click="ButtonOperation"`. In the future put you can put a name more fitting for the operation.
2. Place the mouse cursor anywhere within the `"{name}"` text just created.
3. Push the <kbd>F12</kbd> key and you will be taken to code behind where the named method will be installed for you with the appropriate parameters.
4. To test put in `MessageBox.Show("Jabberwocky");` in the method, compile and run
5. When you click on the button note that the messagebox pops up with "Jabberwocky".